Different Type III Sums of Squares from car Package
I am looking for Type III sums of squares. I understand Type III SS will by default not agree with SAS. However, I have run the following two models and get differing results. I realize my lack of understanding probably lies in me not understanding the constr.poly() statement. I have looked online and cannot seem to find a straightforward answer. Any and all help is appreciated!
install.packages("librarian")
librarian::shelf(car)

mtcars$cylC <- factor(mtcars$cyl)

model <- lm(mpg ~ cylC*disp, data=mtcars, contrasts=list(cylC=contr.poly))
car::Anova(model, type="III")
## Anova Table (Type III tests)
## 
## Response: mpg
##             Sum Sq Df  F value    Pr(>F)    
## (Intercept) 937.97  1 166.7687 8.101e-13 ***
## cylC        137.46  2  12.2201 0.0001814 ***
## disp         90.79  1  16.1415 0.0004465 ***
## cylC:disp    97.39  2   8.6574 0.0013133 ** 
## Residuals   146.23 26                       
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 *** 0.001 ** 0.01 * 0.05 . 0.1   1


model <- lm(mpg ~ cylC*disp, data=mtcars)
car::Anova(model, contrasts=list(cylC=contr.poly), type="III")
## Anova Table (Type III tests)
## 
## Response: mpg
##              Sum Sq Df  F value    Pr(>F)    
## (Intercept) 1030.10  1 183.1477 2.791e-13 ***
## cylC         137.46  2  12.2201 0.0001814 ***
## disp         131.88  1  23.4472 5.096e-05 ***
## cylC:disp     97.39  2   8.6574 0.0013133 ** 
## Residuals    146.23 26                       
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 *** 0.001 ** 0.01 * 0.05 . 0.1   1 

I Googled Type III SS and looked at several pages. I looked at the R online help (car, constr.poly, constrasts, Anova). I looked at numerous pages discussing Type III SS and R including Venables' Exegesis.
I would expect both Type III SS to agree. At this point, I Clearly, I do not understand at a fundamental level.

Apologies...the last lines should read, "I would expect both Type III SS to agree. At this point, I am not sure which are the correct Type III SS or why they differ.I Clearly, I do not understand at a fundamental level."

Click on "Edit" to edit your post.

In ?car::Anova it says:

... do not use.

Because there is no contrasts argument in car::Anova() the one you supplied is being passed in ... and is being ignored with no warning.
Here are examples of excluding and including contrasts=list(cylC=contr.poly) in your calls to car::Anova() on a model that does not include contrasts=list(cylC=contr.poly) and one that does. As you can see, the output is the same per model which tells us including the argument in car::Anova() is being silently ignored.
I recommend that if you want to set contrasts, do it when you define the model in lm() and not post-hoc in car::Anova(). I say this because there is an icontrasts argument in car::Anova(), but it is not as flexible.
Model 1 (No poly)
mtcars$cylC <- factor(mtcars$cyl)

model_1 <- lm(mpg ~ cylC*disp, data=mtcars)

car::Anova(model_1, type="III")
#> Anova Table (Type III tests)
#> 
#> Response: mpg
#>              Sum Sq Df  F value    Pr(>F)    
#> (Intercept) 1030.10  1 183.1477 2.791e-13 ***
#> cylC         137.46  2  12.2201 0.0001814 ***
#> disp         131.88  1  23.4472 5.096e-05 ***
#> cylC:disp     97.39  2   8.6574 0.0013133 ** 
#> Residuals    146.23 26                       
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

car::Anova(model_1, contrasts=list(cylC=contr.poly), type="III")
#> Anova Table (Type III tests)
#> 
#> Response: mpg
#>              Sum Sq Df  F value    Pr(>F)    
#> (Intercept) 1030.10  1 183.1477 2.791e-13 ***
#> cylC         137.46  2  12.2201 0.0001814 ***
#> disp         131.88  1  23.4472 5.096e-05 ***
#> cylC:disp     97.39  2   8.6574 0.0013133 ** 
#> Residuals    146.23 26                       
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Model 2 (with poly)
model_2 <- lm(mpg ~ cylC*disp, data=mtcars, contrasts=list(cylC=contr.poly))

car::Anova(model_2, type="III")
#> Anova Table (Type III tests)
#> 
#> Response: mpg
#>             Sum Sq Df  F value    Pr(>F)    
#> (Intercept) 937.97  1 166.7687 8.101e-13 ***
#> cylC        137.46  2  12.2201 0.0001814 ***
#> disp         90.79  1  16.1415 0.0004465 ***
#> cylC:disp    97.39  2   8.6574 0.0013133 ** 
#> Residuals   146.23 26                       
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

car::Anova(model_2, contrasts=list(cylC=contr.poly), type="III")
#> Anova Table (Type III tests)
#> 
#> Response: mpg
#>             Sum Sq Df  F value    Pr(>F)    
#> (Intercept) 937.97  1 166.7687 8.101e-13 ***
#> cylC        137.46  2  12.2201 0.0001814 ***
#> disp         90.79  1  16.1415 0.0004465 ***
#> cylC:disp    97.39  2   8.6574 0.0013133 ** 
#> Residuals   146.23 26                       
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Created on 2024-04-22 with reprex v2.1.0
